# credit card form submission on a bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I created bootstrap modal for my credit card payment form i want validate the credit card form now am using basic validation in jquery.

```
<script>
$(function() {
$('#error_message_reg').text("");
//$( "submitBtnRegister" ).click(function() {
$('#register_form').on('submit', function()  {
 //e.preventDefault();
var error=false; 
var firstName = $('#payment_first_name').val();
var lastName = $('#payment_last_name').val();
var adress = $('#payment_address').val();
var city = $('#payment_city').val();
var state = $('#payment_state').val();
var zip = $('#payment_zip').val();
var country = $('#payment_country').val();
var cc_no = $('#payment_card_no').val();
var cc_month = $('#payment_card_expiry_month').val();
var cc_year = $('#payment_card_expiry_year').val();
var cc_ccv = $('#payment_card_ccv').val();
var postal_code = $('#payment_card_postal_code').val();






if(firstName == null || firstName == "") {
            $('#error_message_reg').text("FIrst name is required");
            var error=true;
            return false;
        }



if(lastName == null || lastName == "") {
            $('#error_message_reg').text("Last name is required.");
            var error=true;
            return false;
        }
if(adress == null || adress == "") {
            $('#error_message_reg').text("Adress is required.");
            var error=true;
            return false;
        }
if(city == null || city == "") {
            $('#error_message_reg').text("City is required.");
            var error=true;
            return false;
        }
if(state == null || state == "") {
            $('#error_message_reg').text("state is required.");
            var error=true;
            return false;
        }
if(zip == null || zip == "") {
            $('#error_message_reg').text("Zip is required.");
            var error=true;
            return false;
        }
if(country == null || country == "") {
            $('#error_message_reg').text("country is required.");
            var error=true;
            return false;
        }
if(cc_no == null || cc_no == "") {
            $('#error_message_reg').text("Card number is required.");
            var error=true;
            return false;
        }
if(cc_month == null || cc_month == "") {
            $('#error_message_reg').text("expiry month is required.");
            var error=true;
            return false;
        }
if(cc_year == null || cc_year == "") {
            $('#error_message_reg').text("expiry year is required.");
            var error=true;
            return false;
        }
if(cc_ccv == null || cc_ccv == "") {
            $('#error_message_reg').text("CVV is required.");
            var error=true;
            return false;
        }
if(postal_code == null || postal_code == "") {
            $('#error_message_reg').text("postal code is required.");
            var error=true;
            return false;
        }
if(error==false)
{
        $('#error_message_reg').text("");
        $('#register_form').submit();

}
});
});
</script>
```

I would like to add credit card validation also like is this card is valid.
i use braintree as my payment gateway i can check valid transaction using `$result->errors->deepAll()`
but when i submit the form the modal getting closed.Is there any way to prevent closing the modal until the response from braintree comes.
Is it possible to do this without using a ajax.

Thank in advance

Comment: Are you pci compliant?

Comment: Am just a entry level programmer what is _pci compliant_?

Comment: check this https://articles.braintreepayments.com/reference/security/pci-compliance

Comment: currently am working on a sand box account

Comment: `Is there any way to prevent closing the modal until the response from braintree comes. Is it possible to do this without using a ajax.` No I don't think so, reason you have `action=""` in your form and the moment you hit submit it will submit the form 2nd how you send and receive the response from payment gateway if no Ajax method call?

Comment: Don't even dream of taking credit card details until you understand pci compliance

Answer (score 0):

There no way to do a server side validation without page refresh (AS YOU HAVE ALREADY TOLD WITHOUT USING AJAX), when the page refresh the modal will be closed.

OR ELSE we need to reopen the modal on page submission by passing some parameters in URL by validating the card.

```
    <?php if(invalid card): ?>
<script>
reopen the modal with parameters posted
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I suggest using AJAX will be the best way to do. At the bottom of your code you can add

```
if(error==false)
{

$.post( "url to do server side validation", $("#register_form").serialize())
  .done(function( data ) {    //Better to have JSON as response
if(data.success === true)
{
    $('#error_message_reg').text("");
        $('#register_form').submit();
}
else
{
    $('#error_message_reg').text("error from response");
    return false;
}
  });

}
```